# Run-at document-start Tampermonkey Userscript loads later on Firefox than on Edge

Tags: firefox, tampermonkey

I have a Tampermonkey Userscript that I want to use to prevent certain scripts from loading. To do this, I have a MutationObserver and when the scripts appear, I `.remove()` them. This works fine on edge (and presumably other chromium browsers, though I haven't tested), but on Firefox it runs into a problem. The script gets run *after* the scripts get added, despite running at document-start. I confirmed this by adding a `console.log()` statement that prints out one of the scripts and on Firefox it printed the script, whereas on edge it printed nothing. I need to dynamically determine whether the scripts should be removed, so unfortunately @webRequest is a no-go. Is this impossible due to limitations on Firefox, or is there some way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out! Tampermonkey has an experimental setting on advanced config mode for instant script injection, which does what I want. Unfortunately, there's a whole other issue with Firefox where calling `.remove()` on a script doesn't prevent it from executing.